# c# SslException: SSL Handshake failed with OpenSSL error - SSL_ERROR_SSL

Tags: .net, sql-server-2012, sslhandshakeexception, sslexception

This error occurs on a single endpoint.
It is the one that tries to extract data from SqlServer.
If I try to run IIS everything works fine.
When I run in a linux docker container, it doesn't work anymore.
I have the following errors:

OpenSslCryptographicException: error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol

Unknown location
SslException: SSL Handshake failed with OpenSSL error - SSL_ERROR_SSL.

Interop+OpenSsl.DoSslHandshake(SafeSslHandle context, ReadOnlySpan input, out byte[] sendBuf, out int sendCount)
AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception.

System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync(TIOAdapter adapter, bool receiveFirst, byte[] reAuthenticationData, bool isApm)
SqlException: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, bool breakConnection, Action wrapCloseInAction)

SecurityNegotiationException: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority '....'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ri8xH.png)

Comment: Sounds like you are running a .NET instance in a docker container that has a strong security policy configured for OpenSSL which disallows older (and weaker, less ecure) SSL versions that SqlServer tries to use. What container are you using?

Comment: Does the server support TLS 1.2? For SQL Server 2012 you need this update https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb3135244-tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server-e4472ef8-90a9-13c1-e4d8-44aad198cdbe and you also need to enable relevant registry settings if on Windows 7 or 2012r2 or earlier

Answer (score 6):

If absolutely required you can lower minimum required TLS version of OpenSSL in your runtime Docker container. Add following lines somewhere prior ENTRYPOINT in your `Dockerfile`:

```
# fix for SQLServer 2008 R2 - reduce minimum protocol to tls v1.0
RUN sed -i -e "s|^MinProtocol = .*|MinProtocol = TLSv1.0|g" "/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf"
```

But upgrading SQL Server so it support latest TLS versions seems to be a correct solution here.

Comment: I'm still getting issues with this: `System.IO.IOException:  Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.`